# rhythm guitar sound on 'only tomorrow' (my bloody valentine) (pedals?amps?guitars?mic placement? etc.)

Tags: mixing, amplifier, guitar, microphone-positioning

i'm mostly active on stack overflow, but as i like the overall platform/concept so much i figured i'd give this here a try!

basically,  my question is in the title, and here's a link to the song:

i'm referring to the heavily distorted guitar that somehow still blends into the background (listening on bose quiet comfort headphones); it plays on the quarter notes. i'm wondering what techniques might have been used, both in regard to the guitar sound (i.e. pedals, amps, guitars) and to the overall recording/mixing/mastering process, and how *you* would go about replicating this sound in a modest home studio.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually chosen an incredibly difficult question to answer as Kevin from mbv has a lot of pedals in use. This is his main board:

[image]

And he also uses a couple of other boards on stage as well, switching between them. I don't think anyone has a list of his settings used in that song, but check out [effectsbay.com's article here](http://www.effectsbay.com/2011/08/kevin-shields-my-bloody-valentine-pedal-boards/).

Comment: yeah. absolutely insane isn't it. he's an absolute pedal-wizard, that's for sure